# Multiple Selenium drivers in EC2 always crash

Tags: selenium, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use an EC2 instance to run several Selenium chromedrivers in parallel. When I run just one, it works fine. But as soon as I start a second Selenium process, both processes fail (as in, page loads hit max timeouts after a couple minutes).

I'm using a t3.large instance, which has 8gb RAM and 5Gbps of network bandwidth. It's not a cheap instance and costs $2 per day. I'm surprised that with these specs, it can't handle two concurrent Selenium processes because my personal laptop has no problem handling 4+ Selenium processes.

Additional info: I'm using pyvirtualdisplay on the EC2 box.

Wondering if I'm missing something here that is causing the poor performance.

Comment: Are you talking about separate processes or threads? what if you do --headless instead of pyvirtualdisplay?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'm using separate processes (ie running `python myFile.py` in two windows at once). Unfortunately --headless is not an option for this because the website is able to detect Selenium in this case.